# How to host custome activity on Web server

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sales-cloud, custom-activity

I have created one custom activity in Marketing Cloud I am getting below errors , please guide me how to resolve this.This error is due to Web server hosting.[image]

Comment: I would open dev tools and go to the network tab and review the URL that is throwing an error

Answer (score 0):

please start by going through the troubleshooting guide by salesforce:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/troubleshoot-custom-activities.htm

Furthermore, please explain what you already tried to solve this issue.
My first guess would be that your Endpoint URL doesnt start with https.

Comment: So i have create one package in Marketing cloud then one component i.e. custome activity

Comment: And does the link to your web server have a ssl cert?

Comment: no ..i have not can u please tell me which tool do i use for ths and how to do it ?

Comment: okay this is getting off topic more and more. please inform yourself about how you get a ssl cert for your server. and please go through the trouble shooting list. SSL is first on the list.